# Getting results from Ref Cursor Oracle using ProcedureCall hibernate to createStoredProcedureCall

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, stored-procedures

I'm using ProcedureCall to create stored procedure:

```
    ProcedureCall procedure=getCurrentSession().createStoredProcedureCall("getContractServiceForContract");
    procedure.registerParameter(1, ResultSet.class , ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);
    procedure.registerParameter(2, Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    procedure.registerParameter(3, Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    procedure.registerParameter(4, Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);

    procedure.getParameterRegistration(2).bindValue(contractId);
    procedure.getParameterRegistration(3).bindValue(month);
    procedure.getParameterRegistration(4).bindValue(year);
```

After this i have:

```
    ResultSetOutput rso=(ResultSetOutput) procedure.getOutputs().getCurrent();
```

But

> getCurrent();

Throws exception:

```
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect does not support resultsets via stored procedures
```

I was trying to use expression:

```
 ResultSetOutput rso=(ResultSetOutput)procedure.getOutputs().getOutputParameterValue(1);
```

But again i got exception:

```
 org.hibernate.procedure.ParameterMisuseException: REF_CURSOR parameters should be accessed via results
```

Any ideas how to make this work? My procedure starts with:

```
PROCEDURE getContractServiceForContract 
(
  pResultValue OUT PROCTYPES.ref_cursor,
  pContractID IN INT,
  pMonth IN INT,
  pYear IN INT,
  pIsLoadByAccountingPeriod IN INT default 0
) AS 
yearMin int;
yearMax int;
monthMin int;
monthMax int;
vContractIDs t_num_ids_tab;       --holds event id's
vContractServIDs t_num_ids_tab;       --holds event id's
BEGIN   ...
```

Comment: Please find the work around for the issue here http://blog.harpoontech.com/2013/05/using-oracle-stored-procedures-and-java.html

Comment: http://blog.harpoontech.com/2013/05/using-oracle-stored-procedures-and-java.html
Here there is 
> CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall("call jay_proc(?)");
But i want to use ProcedureCall because i can't use Connection variable to declare CallableStatement. Connection is establishing in core of my application so i don't want to get access to this.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/jdbc_42.html

Answer (score 0):

It's work. I get List of objects array.

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery(GET_GOODS_PROCEDURE)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, GoodTest.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, String.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(3, Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT);

        query.execute();
        List<Object[]> goods = query.getResultList();

        for (Object[] good : goods) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(good));
        }
```